# How does one change any of the values in the System Information section on Windows 10/11?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-11, oem

Is it possible to modify any of the values on the System Information window in Windows 10/11? I found some articles about updating the OEM Information from regedit but this seems to have zero impact.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The screen you show is from MSINFO32.EXE and that is a display, not an editor.

So for this screen (both Windows 10 and 11 (I am using Windows 11 with a Windows 10 VM), no, you cannot edit these values within msinfo.

Some of the items can be edited (Windows information via Advanced System Properties) and other would be properties of (say) the Device Driver for the item.

So it depends on what you wish to change (if you can change the value) how you would do it. There is a a no simple one way or simple editor that will edit all these items.